# Rotate a point in 3D space with sine and cosine

Tags: c++, opengl, mathematics

I got my camera controlled by the mouse. Now I want a sphere to be always in the center of my view(just for testing). I tried that by assigning the sine of the Y rotation of the camera times 10 as the X coordinate and the same for the Y coordinate but with cosine:

```
SphereX = 10 * math.sin(YRotation)
SphereY = 10 * math.cos(YRotation)
```

But now I would like to know how to set the Z position. I can set the proper height of the sphere by doing that:

```
SphereZ = 10 * math.sin(XRotation)
```

But the problem is, that the sphere is only moving up and down and the moving towards the camera is ignored. How can I fix that?

Comment: You want the sphere to be in front of the camera, at a constant distance no matter where you move the camera? Or you want to do something like orbiting the sphere and being able to zoom in and out on it?

Comment: The first one. :D

Comment: Are you set on using sine and cosine? Might be easier with matrices: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11594

Comment: Actually I just want the direction the camera is looking at. I wanted to solve that by calculating a kind of a target.

Comment: Got it working. The camera direction is the negative of the third row of the viewing matrix.

Comment: Cool, post it as an answer after the waiting period.

Comment: It's actually the 3rd row of the inverted view matrix which is sometimes the same as the negative of the 3rd row of the view but not always. It would be safer to invert the view, then grab the 3rd row.